# UITabBarController Initial View?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

I'm wondering if it is possible to start my app with all my tabs in the "up" state and show a "landing" view to the user. Kind of like a welcome/quick start. When they select one of the tabs, it switches views as normal.

Will you point me in the right direction?

Kind of like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `UITabBar`/`UITabBarController`, I think you must have the `selectedIndex` set to some legal value. I don't think this is possible, nor can I find an app on my iPhone or iPod that mimics the behaviour you're looking for.

(The App Store app is as close as it gets, where it *looks* like it has an empty tab bar before it loads data from the Internet, but it could very well be that they are just re-using the Default.png and superimposing an activity indicator during loading.)

Note that if you tried to submit your app to Apple, they could easily reject it for using non-standard UI.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would probably do this is to create a new ViewController that's just for this screen, but make sure it's *last* in the `viewControllers` array managed by the `UITabBarController`.  That way, when you show the tab bar on the screen, you get the 4 tabs and the more button, but the currently selected view controller is not in the bar, meaning that all of the other tabs are unselected.

Once the user has satisfied the condition for showing the screen, you can discretely remove the view controller from the tab bar, and the user will never be the wiser.